# Insert an array in an Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a collection of data which is like this:

```
const listItem = [
    {name:'Patrick star',id:"1",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'}]},
    {name:'Gallileo',id:"2",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'},{name:'Walking'}]},
    {name:'Einsten',id:"3",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'}]},
    {name:'Peterson',id:"4",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'}]},
    {name:'Schwarzenneger',id:"5",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'}]},
    {name:'Dostoyevsky',id:"6",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'}]}
]
```

I want to make an array like this. Now i have

```
var arr = []
var costs = [{name: "20"}]
var category = {id: 3, name: "envelope"}
```

I need to put the `costs` array and `category` in a single array. Here's the wanted output:

```
[{name:'envelope',id:"3",costs:[{name: "20"}]}]
```

How can i do that?

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: I have updated the wanted result. Please check. @NinaScholz

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread operator like this:

```
var costs = [{name: "20"}]
var category = {id: 3, name: "envelope"}
var arr = [{costs: [...costs], ...category}]
```

Comment: It creates two different arrays. But i need one. I have updated the wanted result. Please check. @VoQuocThang

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
let items = {"name": category['name'], "id": category['id'], "costs": costs}
arr.push(items)
```

Another simpler method:

```js
arr.push({"costs": costs, ...category})
```

and append items in a loop if necessary

Result:

```
[{name:'envelope',id:3,costs:[{name: "20"}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put costs and category in a single object and then you can put that object into Array like this  :

```
var arr = []
var costs = [{name: "20"}]
var category = {id: 3, name: "envelope"}
arr.push({ costs, ...category });
```

Array will look like this after push :

```
arr = [
          {
              costs : [{name: "20"}],
              id: 3, 
              name: "envelope"
          }
      ]
```

Comment: I have updated the wanted result. Please check. @mayurkukadiya

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your problem

```
<script>
const listItem = [
    {name:'Patrick star',id:"1",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'}]},
    {name:'Gallileo',id:"2",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'},{name:'Walking'}]},
    {name:'Einsten',id:"3",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'}]},
    {name:'Peterson',id:"4",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'}]},
    {name:'Schwarzenneger',id:"5",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'}]},
    {name:'Dostoyevsky',id:"6",costs:[{name:'Read Book'},{name:'Drink water'}]}
]

var arr = []
var costs = [{name: "20"}]
var category = {id: 3, name: "envelope"}

category['costs']=costs


// Just to Verify
console.log(JSON.stringify(listItem)) //[{"name":"Patrick star","id":"1","costs":[{"name":"Read Book"},{"name":"Drink water"}]},{"name":"Gallileo","id":"2","costs":[{"name":"Read Book"},{"name":"Drink water"},{"name":"Walking"}]},{"name":"Einsten","id":"3","costs":[{"name":"Read Book"},{"name":"Drink water"}]},{"name":"Peterson","id":"4","costs":[{"name":"Read Book"},{"name":"Drink water"}]},{"name":"Schwarzenneger","id":"5","costs":[{"name":"Read Book"},{"name":"Drink water"}]},{"name":"Dostoyevsky","id":"6","costs":[{"name":"Read Book"},{"name":"Drink water"}]}]

listItem.push(category)  // this is how you insert data in exiting object

console.log(JSON.stringify(listItem))//[{"name":"Patrick star","id":"1","costs":[{"name":"Read Book"},{"name":"Drink water"}]},{"name":"Gallileo","id":"2","costs":[{"name":"Read Book"},{"name":"Drink water"},{"name":"Walking"}]},{"name":"Einsten","id":"3","costs":[{"name":"Read Book"},{"name":"Drink water"}]},{"name":"Peterson","id":"4","costs":[{"name":"Read Book"},{"name":"Drink water"}]},{"name":"Schwarzenneger","id":"5","costs":[{"name":"Read Book"},{"name":"Drink water"}]},{"name":"Dostoyevsky","id":"6","costs":[{"name":"Read Book"},{"name":"Drink water"}]},{"id":3,"name":"envelope","costs":[{"name":"20"}]}]
</script>
```